# Find the nearest element of a certain type to $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">

<h3>Fileset 1</h3>

<ul class="fileset-list">
        <li><a href="#">File 1.pdf</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Fileset 2</h3>

<ul class="fileset-list">

        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">File 2.doc</a></li>     
        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">File 3.csv</a></li>
        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">File 4.xlsx</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Fileset 3</h3>

<ul class="fileset-list">

        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">File 5.pdf</a></li>

</div>
```

If for instance I am accessing the `<li>` with `File 4.xlsx`in it then how would I target the preceeding `h3` element.

Currently I have something like this :

```
<br><label class="label label-default" for="searchDocuments">Search </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchDocuments" id="searchDocuments">

<ul id="searchResults">

</ul>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#searchClear').click(function(){
        $('#searchDocuments').val("");
    })
    var resultsList = $('#searchResults');
    var items = $('.fileset-list li');
    $('#searchDocuments').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    items.each(function( index ) {

  var innerHtmlTemp = $( this ).html().toLowerCase();
  if((innerHtmlTemp.indexOf(value) > -1)) {
            $(this).show(500);
            $(this).closest('h3').show(500);    // Find closest h3 and show it           
            } else {
                $(this).hide(500)
                **$(this).closest('h3').hide(500); // Find closest h3 and hide it
            }
            if($.trim(value) == ""){
                items.show(500);
                ('h3').show(); // Find all h3's and show them if the search box is empty
            }

        });

    });
})

</script>
```

So I am searching for an `<li>` element, on finding it hides all the other non-matching `<li>` elements. But I also want it to hide the corresponding title for those elements if it doesnt find a match for atleast one list item. Hopefully that makes sense. Potentially, I always might want these "matching" results to clone the element in the searchResults div (with hyperlinks still intact) and once the term changes in search box it removes it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is not easy, but I suggest adding attributes to link between each group of "a" elements and the nearest "h3" element .. by this way once you find the matched "a", you can show/grape the related "h3"

I've prepared this sample (I've skipped whatever you do to select the matched "a") But you may want to use the "contains" method for searching.

I'm writing the text of matched h3 in the log (browser log)

**Edit: I've changed the code so, you will not need to add more attributes**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  /* New Solution */
  console.log($("li a:contains('File 5.pdf')").parents("ul").first().prev("h3").text());
  
   console.log($("li a:contains('File 3.csv')").parents("ul").first().prev("h3").text());
  
  console.log($("li a:contains('File 1.pdf')").parents("ul").first().prev("h3").text());
  
  /* Old Solution */
  /*var h3ID=$("li a:contains('File 3.csv')").attr("data-parent");
  console.log($("#"+h3ID).text());
  
  var h3ID=$("li a:contains('File 1')").attr("data-parent");
  console.log($("#"+h3ID).text());
  
  var h3ID=$("li a:contains('File 5.pdf')").attr("data-parent");
  console.log($("#"+h3ID).text());*/
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">

<h3 id="h3_1">Fileset 1</h3>

<ul class="fileset-list">
        <li><a href="#" data-parent="h3_1">File 1.pdf</a></li>
</ul>

<h3 id="h3_2">Fileset 2</h3>

<ul class="fileset-list">

        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#" data-parent="h3_2">File 2.doc</a></li>     
        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#" data-parent="h3_2">File 3.csv</a></li>
        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#" data-parent="h3_2">File 4.xlsx</a></li>
</ul>

<h3 id="h3_3">Fileset 3</h3>

<ul class="fileset-list">

        <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#" data-parent="h3_3">File 5.pdf</a></li>

</div>
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can see your answer works however as the elements are generated for me I can't add attributes to them unfortunately otherwise this would make my life easier!

Comment: @MrDansk I've edited my solution, you can check the updated code, by this new technique you wouldn't need to change the HTML structure ... Hope this one works :)

Answer (score -1):

The first parent matching the selector('h3') is your preceding element

Here is the easy way -

`$('this').parents('h3').first()`

This will give **Fileset 2**

Comment: None of the `h3`s in the question have any child elements, so `anything.parents("h3")` will always find nothing.

Comment: This solution will not work as h3 is not one of the parent tags for the "a" tag